# Performance tuning query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to performance Tune a Query. My Query is a dynamic one and Goes below

```
store_1:='select  item_number from Tab_1 
          where subclass_id= ' || part_class_id || ' 
            and category_id= '|| part_type_id || ' 
            and delete_flag=0 
            and text11 != ''' || i.eccn_old ||'''' ;

open cursor for store_1;
loop
     fetch cursor into record;
     exit when record%notfound;

    select count(1) into variable from Tab_1 a, Tab_2 b 
    where a.id=b.id
    and a.item_number=record
    and some condition;

   if (variable>0) then
     insert into table tab_3 values(record);
     commit;
   end if;
end loop;


The time taken by above code in approx 1 min for 150 Cursor records.
```

The table Tab_1 (1495093) rows and Tab_2 (6580252) rows are large in size.

Also the output of store_1 will have more than 100 rows but again depends on the condition 
but in very rare case would exceed 5000.

I tried to tune the overall process by creating global temp table "tab_4" and joining it with the "tab_2" table and directly inserting into my "Tab_3" table.

```
Note tab_4 has only one column "item_number"
```

My Attempt goes below

```
store_1:='insert into tab_4 select item_number from tab_1 
          where subclass_id= ' || part_class_id || ' 
          and category_id= ' || part_type_id || ' 
          and delete_flag=0 and text11 != ''' || i.eccn_old ||'''' ;

execute immediate store_1;    
commit;

insert into tab_3 select  b.item_number from  tab_1 a, tab_4 b
                  where a.item_number=b.item_number                                                                                                                        
                  and b.release_date> somedate
                  and b.delete_flag=0
                  and (b.release_type =974 or b.release_type =975);
```

I thought join table would do the trick but unfortunately my process even takes more time

```
The time taken was approx 3 min for 150 Cursor Records
```

Please guide me tunning the code, So that my approximate time reduces by 50-60 % atleast.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL in the first place?  The example you posted isn't doing anything that requires or even benefits from using dynamic SQL.  If you are going to use dynamic SQL, is there a reason that you aren't using bind variables?  Is there a reason that you are using PL/SQL in the first place rather than writing a single `INSERT` statement?

Comment: As a first note... did you try putting the commit *after* all the inserts are done. I'm not sure about Oracle, but other engines are much more performing with a single final commit. At least in you original query this could make some difference.

Comment: The whole procedure was taking more than 7 hrs because of large dataset, Hence I put commit to track the latest row_number that was inserted so I can start from that particular row_number if the session abruptly ends. but ya point considered my procedure wont have commit after every insert when the code goes to production.

Comment: Justin: The Store_1 query keeps on changing for different scenarios There may be few table and columns which the user is oblivious of but the names are derived from dictionary table on certain condition and the store_1 might include such tables and columns for join and where condition Query hence had to use dynamic statement. I didn't see any opportunity for bind variable hence didn't use any. Well if you see any please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in store_1 try to rewrite the where clause by make the first condition with columns which have primary keys, unique keys, then followed by other conditions.
2. create indexes on tab_1 for (subclass_id, category_id)
3. create index on tab_1 for item_number.
4. re-run and check the performance again.

note: creating indexes could take a while, so be patient.